# mounting xfs linux partition in High Sierra

Tags: osx, xfs

I am trying to mount a 2TB xfs partition on an external disk in a new Macbook Pro with High Sierra.

I have already installed osxfuse-3.7.1 and fuse-xfs-0.2.1 ; it did not work out. The disk is not auto-mounted when I connect it to the USB port.

`diskutil list` shows:

```
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk2
   1:           Linux Filesystem                         2.0 TB     disk2s1
```

Do you have any more suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My proposal of mounting is to run `Linux` on a Virtual Machine, expose the block-device directly, mount it inside `Linux` with well written driver and use shared-directories.

I do not trust `fuse` at all. I faced many issues with `ntfs` as well.